# SQLAlchemy Automap not generating Base.classes with existing MySQL tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, automap

I am using an existing mysql database which has pre existing tables. Everything works as expected when I manually create classes/ models using the declarative approach. Now, I want to use automap to avoid creating models manually. As the database is from work, I cannot edit it. Second, the primary keys are present already(Most posts I have read mention primary keys not being present on the table as the reason).
I have been looking around for a couple of days but have not found a solution.
Example below :

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = automap_base()
engine = create_engine('working-as-expected')
Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)

print('Hello2 - base classes items')
print(Base.classes.items()) # output is []
print('Hello3 - metadata keys')
print(Base.metadata.tables.keys()) # output is []
```

example of an existing mysql table :

```
CREATE TABLE 'tbl_Xyz' (
'ID' int(11) NOT NULL,
'Name' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('ID'))
```

What should I do differently ?

Comment: Works for me.  What connector are you using? Is the user authorised to see and select from the tables?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, I have access to select data from tables. By connector, did you mean - 'mysql+pymysql' ?

Comment: I get empty list even when I use sqlite. 

    Base = automap_base()
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")
    Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)


print('Hello2 - base classes items')
print(Base.classes.items())
print('Hello3 - metadata keys')
print(Base.metadata.tables.keys())

Comment: I've had issues with case insensitivity and mysql so it could also be related to that.  Can you provide more details about the versions you are using?  Also try to output show tables and maybe include some logging info from running echo=True on the engine?

Comment: will do this and share soon. Thanks.

Comment: Do `with engine.connect() as conn:` followed by `print(conn.exec_driver_sql("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_os'").one())` - What does it display?

Comment: @GordThompson I got : __enter__ (two underscores before and after enter)

Comment: Okay, then just run the `SHOW VARIABLES` query in MySQL Workbench or whatever.

Comment: @GordThompson I still get __enter__ . Just to add, I am triggering the python script via Jenkins. Not sure if it makes any difference as SQLAlchemy (manual creation of models) worked this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, do you think you might not be referencing the correct database name?  I used the `mysql:8` docker container to run mysql.

In addition to all the logging from `echo=True` on the engine this script prints this:
`[('tbl_Xyz',)]`

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_IP}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}', echo=True)



with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    conn.execute(text('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_Xyz (
ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(45) NOT NULL)'''))
    print ([row for row in conn.execute(text('''
SHOW TABLES'''))])

Base = automap_base()

Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)

assert len(Base.classes.items()) > 0
assert Base.classes.tbl_Xyz
assert Base.classes.tbl_Xyz.__table__ is not None
assert Base.classes.tbl_Xyz.__table__.c.ID is not None
```

Comment: I used the same database name when I created models manually and everything worked.

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy==1.4.45 and PyMySQL==1.0.2 and mysql Ver 8.0.31 for linux.

Comment: Maybe try just using the engine directly and listing the tables.  I included that in my example via `conn.execute(text('''
SHOW TABLES'''))`.

Comment: I am using SQLAlchemy==2.0.20

Comment: show tables gives me all table names in my mysql work databse

Comment: I just created a table in sqllite and automap worked with it. Just wondering if there is something about existing tables in my mysql database.

Comment: @ManikaMidha I would try to reflect the tables and see if that works.  Maybe sqlalchemy cannot detect the primary keys for some reason.  [reflecting-all-tables-at-once](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html#reflecting-all-tables-at-once)

Comment: Also the underlying tool used I think is the inspector.  You can use that directly and maybe that would further reveal what is going wrong:  [fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector)

Comment: Hello, inspect get_table_names returned [] and using reflecting-all-tables-at-once gives the same attribute error as Base.classes.table_name

Comment: Just an FYI, I am triggerring the python script via Jenkins.  May be, it will not make any difference as I could create models manually easily the same way.